# CPAN testers error attempting to make script target

Tags: perl, cpan

I recently uploaded a [package](http://search.cpan.org/%7Ejeffober/Argon/lib/Argon.pm) to CPAN and am [receiving errors from the automated CPAN tests](http://www.cpantesters.org/cpan/report/c5e2a1f6-f508-11e2-8f75-553d14be7dd6). The package comes with several scripts: `bin/node` and `bin/cluster`. They are listed in my `Makefile.PL` like so:

```
EXE_FILES => [ 'bin/cluster', 'bin/node' ]
```

However, when the tests are run, I get emails detailing the following error:

```
TEST RESULTS:

Below is the error stack from stage 'make test':

cp lib/Argon/Node.pm blib/lib/Argon/Node.pm
cp lib/Argon/Queue.pm blib/lib/Argon/Queue.pm
cp lib/Argon/Message.pm blib/lib/Argon/Message.pm
cp lib/Argon/Cluster.pm blib/lib/Argon/Cluster.pm
cp lib/Argon/Worker.pm blib/lib/Argon/Worker.pm
cp lib/Argon/Stream.pm blib/lib/Argon/Stream.pm
cp lib/Argon/NodeTracker.pm blib/lib/Argon/NodeTracker.pm
cp lib/Argon/Client.pm blib/lib/Argon/Client.pm
cp lib/Argon.pm blib/lib/Argon.pm
cp lib/Argon/Role/Task.pm blib/lib/Argon/Role/Task.pm
cp lib/Argon/Server.pm blib/lib/Argon/Server.pm
cp lib/Argon/Process.pm blib/lib/Argon/Process.pm
make: don't know how to make bin/node. Stop
```

I am not certain as to why I am getting this error. When I run `make test` locally, I get no errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `bin/cluster` and `bin/node` to your `MANIFEST` file.

Comment: Sometimes it's not enough to run `make test` locally. You need to `make dist`, then unpack the distribution into a fresh directory, and then `make test`.

Comment: Thank you both. I will update the MANIFEST, repackage and upload. And thanks, mob, for your note. That is an important distinction.